# How to setup stellar exchange functionality in sample demo wallet

Tags: wallets, anchor

I want to transfer INR asset from my side and destination account get it in the form of USD asset. How can I implement this functionality in my sample demo wallet. Right now I am working on it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to implement path payments.Path payments allow a user to send an asset they already hold, and to convert it in transit into an asset a recipient wants to receive.

You could create a market for INR/XLM and USD/XLM on testnet to facilitate the path payments. I created a script not too long ago that can streamline the market process a bit: https://github.com/koltenb/stellar-asset-issuer-script

Comment: it require outstanding offer (orderbook) to work. I have created an offer, but I have no idea how to create an entry to the orderbook, do you know any operation in JS I need to execute in order to have the path payment work?